# NP problem that has a verifier that uses $\leq 3 \log_2 n$ bits of memory, how does that influence the complexity of the problem itself?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

Translated exercise:

> **Algorithms, that solve NP problems.** Let's assume a problem $R$ is in the set $\sf NP$. A verifier $M(x,y)$ for this problem works in time $O(n)$ and *uses
>   extra information $y$, which is is $\leq 3 \log n$ bits*. What $f(n)$ can we
>   say, that $R$ belongs to in ${\sf TIME}(f(n))$?

---

The **only** part I dont get is how a verifier using some (very small) extra memory would influence the problem $R$ beloging to a specific ${\sf TIME}(f(n))$ class.
Please just point me in the right direction.

Any Wikipedia link or a single sentence. My book got nothing.

What does *"extra information $y$, which is is $\leq 3 \log n$ bits"* even mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** the keyword is *enumeration*. That is, you know that for any $x$, if there is a witness $y$ proving $x\in {\sf R}$ then it is small, so you can afford to try out all possible witnesses.

*Stop reading here is you only wanted a clue.*

---

**Outline:**
What it means is that the problem $R\in\sf NP$ satisfies the following. There exists an algorithm $M$ such that for any $x$ of size $\lvert x\rvert = n$:

- if $x\in R$, there there exists $y\in\{0,1\}^\ast$ *with $\lvert y\rvert \leq 3\log_2 n$* such that $M(x,y)=1$;
- if $x\notin R$, there for any $y\in\{0,1\}^\ast$ (in particular with $\lvert y\rvert \leq 3\log_2 n$) we have $M(x,y)=0$.

Moreover, $M$ runs in time $O(n)$, when given inputs $x,y$ with $\lvert x\rvert = n$.

Now, *why does the assumption that the certificate $y$ is small help*? Well, here is the idea:

> Given an input $x$ of size $n$, how much time does it take to try *all* possible $y\in\{0,1\}^\ast$ such that $\lvert y\rvert \leq 3\log_2 n$?

**More detail:** *(spoilers)*

The answer is $O(n^3)$, since there are 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{3\log_2 n} 2^k = \frac{2^{3\log_2 n+1}-1}{2-1} = 2^{3\log_2 n+1}-1 = \frac{n^3}{2}-1
$$
such "candidates" $y$.

So given $M$ as above, on input $x$ of size $n$ once can iterate over **all** possible witnesses $y$ of size at most $3\log_2 n$, and compute $M(x,y)$ for each of them.

- If there exists $y^\ast$ such that $M(x,y^\ast)=1$, return $\sf accept$;
- If there is no $y$ such that $M(x,y)=1$, return $\sf reject$

and the loop overall takes time $O(n^3)\cdot O(n) = O(n^4)$ (checking $O(n^3)$ possibilities, with $O(n)$ computation for each.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) This community is great. I'm gonna study your solution tomorrow and gonna mark as the accepted answer. Sorry I can't upvote as I have not enough karma.

This isn't even a homework question for me as I'm studying for the exam and the full answer is of no use if dont spend time understanding it.

The best clue was that you pointed out that that extra info is the "certificate". I didn't grasp that part.

Comment: Glad I could help. Jumping forward, this sort of "enumeration trick" is also useful in derandomization, for when you study classes like $\sf BPP$, $\sf RP$, and  $\sf ZPP$. Namely, if a randomized algorithm uses "few bits of randomness," then one can make it deterministic by trying it on all possible random strings, and taking a majority vote over all the answers.